# Knockoutjs checkbox validaton using subscribe

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to validate if a checkbox should be checked or not, I am using subscribe, But I am not sure why it is not working, I tried a similar logic with a textfield and it works.  I created a little demo:

```
<input type ="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsSelected"/>
<input type ="text" data-bind="value: Name"/>

var model = {
    IsSelected : ko.observable(false), 
    Name: ko.observable("")
}
var demo = 1;
model.IsSelected.subscribe(function(value){
    if (demo == 2 && value){
        model.IsSelected(false);
    }
    demo = 2; 
});
model.Name.subscribe(function(value){
    if (value == "Set"){
        model.Name("Jose");
    }
})
  ko.applyBindings(model);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xepe/9YXTW/

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks a bit recursive to me. A subscription on a property that then sets the property.

Comment: I created this scenario because I have a list of checkbox and if 2 of them are selected the other should be not selected.

Comment: Please add more details in your question. How do you define checkboxes for unselecting? Add your full viewmodel.

Comment: BTW, for validation it's better to use the [`submit` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the event fires before the browser updates the checkbox and so it ends up looking checked even though `IsSelected` is `false`.  One workaround is to use `_.delay` or `setTimeout` to delay reverting your checkbox to false:

```
model.IsSelected.subscribe(function(value){
    if (demo == 2 && value){
        setTimeout(function () { model.IsSelected(false); }, 0);
    }
    demo = 2; 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9YXTW/17/

Answer (score 2):

With all due respect, I have no idea what you're trying to do from your code. Based on your comment, however:

> I created this scenario because I have a list of checkbox and if 2 of them are selected the other should be not selected.

and your fiddle, I created this:

[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/eBU64/3/)

```
function CheckboxedTextbox(checkboxValue, textboxValue) {
    this.textboxValue = ko.observable(textboxValue);
    this.checkboxValue = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.textboxValue();
    }, this);
    this.isSelected = ko.observable(checkboxValue);
}

function ViewModel() {
    this.checkboxes = ko.observableArray([
        new CheckboxedTextbox(false),
        new CheckboxedTextbox(true, "Default value?"),
        new CheckboxedTextbox(false)
    ]);
    this.valid = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.checkboxes().filter(function(c) {
            return c.isSelected();
        }).length <= 2;
    }, this);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

which will simply tell you whether you have too many selected or not. **Notifying your users of a validation constraint is probably a better pattern for user experience than automatically unchecking boxes they've checked.** However, if you want to force only to be checked at once, I'd use a change handler, and track the most recent change, add this to your view model:

[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/eBU64/5/)

```
    this.lastChangedBox = ko.observable();

    this.forceQuantityChecked = function(newlyChecked) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (!this.valid()) {
                this.checkboxes().filter(function(c) {
                    return c.isSelected() && c !== this.lastChangedBox() && c !== newlyChecked;
                }.bind(this)).forEach(function(c) {
                    c.isSelected(false);
                });
            }
            this.lastChangedBox(newlyChecked);
        }.bind(this), 0);
    };
```

There we do see the need for `setTimeout`.

The big thing to get here is that data is good, which is why we use `observable`s and `computed`s: any sort of idea like "are there too many checkboxes checked" can be expressed as a set of interconnected data: an array of checkboxes, whether each checkbox is checked, and a property describing the validity of the current state of the boxes.